# right outer join calling null on left side (id) when the pair exists

Tags: mysql, sql

The following results in a left hand (table l) "identifier" as null even if there is a pair (ex, there is a f.URL = l.URL and they are both not null) there. The identifier should be considered an auto increment and "URL"s are unique

Is there something obvious i should be doing that I am not?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `l` 
 RIGHT JOIN f ON f.URL = l.URL
 AND f.url <> ''
 AND f.ID = l.id
 AND l.url IS NULL 
 AND l.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Incidentally, RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this, it is because i was doing in on the ON statement:

This could be fixed by adding a where clause after what i intended as the ON statement -

```
SELECT *
 FROM `l` 
 RIGHT JOIN f ON f.URL = l.URL
 WHERE f.url <> ''
 AND f.ID = l.id
 AND l.url IS NULL 
 AND l.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because you have the condition `AND l.id IS NULL`.

Thus, all rows will have `l.id = NULL`. (Or, in your own words, a "lefthand identifier as null".)

Comment: I want to select the information on the right where the information on the left doesn't exist, how do i do that?